# jQuery Show One Div and Hide the Others

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/yrM3H/2/

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".toggle").next(".hidden").hide();
  jQuery(".toggle").click(function()
  { 
    $('.active').toggleClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");   

});
});
```

I have multiple `<div>`'s, and my idea is that when I open a `<div>` it toggles another `<div>`.  And then, when I click another `<div>`, it hides the open `<div>`.  Therefore only one `<div>` is open at a time.

My only issue is that with this code, when I try to close a `<div>` that is already open, it will close and then open again.  Thus one `<div>` will always be open.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

I added the HTML and CSS below.  Everything works fine, except that I cannot get it so that all of them are closed.

I have 5 of these stacked on each other in a wrapper.

*edited for clarity *

```
// HTML
<div class="toggle"></div>
<div  class="hidden"></div>

// CSS
.toggle {width:398px; height:48px; cursor: pointer;}
.hidden {width:300px; height:75px; background-color:#333333; margin-left:50px; text-indent:25px;}
```

Comment: Please put some relevant HTML and CSS code in your OP.  Also, creating a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be great.

Comment: Content has been updated and a jfiddle as been added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will fix it:
http://jsfiddle.net/yrM3H/3/

```
  jQuery(".toggle").click(function()
  { 
    $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");   
  });
```

you have to exclude the clicked element form your ".active" section using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) since the clicked element is ".active" to.