# display a hidden div on link mouseover to appear on top of existing slideshow?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, mouseover, hidden

First time posting a question, but visited the site many many times over.

I'm trying to replicate the effect used on this webiste: http://www.toyota.ca/cgi-bin/WebObjects/WWW.woa/wa/vp?vp=Home&language=english

the slider i can handle, no problem.  but what script or jquery did they use to have the hidden div appear on mouseover of the car model links and show on top of the slider?  i also like the effect given to the list of cars.

Searched stackoverflow and found a link to this post: [mouseover to display appropriated div for link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028562/mouseover-to-display-appropriated-div-for-link)
Would this work to achieve the desired affect?

I'm trying to prepare for a new project and this is a client must have request.  I'm no coder, but I can follow instructions if you speak plainly.

Thanks for your tireless assistance.

Answer (score 0):

They just have a `div` for each car. When you move your mouse over an item, one div is made visible, others are hidden.
You might want to have a look at this question: [jQuery Show One Div and Hide the Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866747/jquery-show-one-div-and-hide-the-others).

The list effect is also simple css. You just toggle a class that makes font and padding larger. To make this transition smooth you can either use [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) ot [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt response.  I was under the impression that there is only one div that overlaps the slider and it's the content that changes on mouseover.  also, it needs to hide all on mouseout?

Comment: @user2426310 You could just open the page source and check yourself. There is a `dif` with `id="vehicle_slides"` and it contains all others. Whether to hide on mouseout or not id your decision. They seem to hide only if mouse leaves the largest div, I don't find it useful, I wouldn't hide at all.